# I thought the mac mini server also serves as a wifi router?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, wireless-networking

I just bought a snow leopard mac mini server, everything came as a bundle pretty nice. The snow leopard server software preinstalled on the mac mini too. Only thing I'm not sure about is does this also act as a wifi router? In the back of the box it says "airport extreme wireless networking included", I assumed this means that this can act as a wifi router like an aiport extreme? Is this true? If so, how do I do it?

According to this artcile http://ipliance.com/index.php/eng/Blog/(day)/4/(month)/1/(year)/2010 I can create an ad hoc wifi, but it doesn't say how to do it. Does anyone know?

Comment: If you are asking if it can function as a wireless base station, the answer is no, it can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of to create a wireless network in OSX is to use the Internet Sharing Options.

Here are the steps to turn it on:

- Apple Menu
- System Preferences
- Sharing
- Click on Internet Sharing (in the left-hand list)
- Select your wired connection (Usually Ethernet 1) under "Share your connection from:"
- Under "To computers using" select your wireless card.
- You can customize the wireless settings by clicking the Wireless Settings button in the lower-right corner of the window.

You won't get WPA encryption (at least not in the desktop version of OSX), but you can use WEP.  From there it should act similar to an Airport Base Station.

Answer (score 3):

Airport Extreme is a generic term used by Apple to mean 802.11n pretty much. It has an Airport Extreme card in it. This is just the wireless card. An Airport Extreme base station is the wifi router/media extender/switch that you were expecting.

Comment: So the answer is it cannot?

Comment: @erotsppa - You can do something like share the Internet connection and route the traffic through the Ethernet connection. But no, there's no neat and easy turnkey solution like you were expecting.